# Am I correct? (Finite Automata)

Tags: finite-automata, turing-machines, dfa, nfa

I was given a regular expression, and I am suppose to covert it to NFA and then DFA. Here's the regular expression:

> a ( b | c )* a | a a c* b

Then I coverted this to NFA using Thomson's algorithm:
[image: NFA]

and here's the DFA:
[image: DFA]

Can someone please take a quick look at let me know if I am wrong or right?

Comment: The DFA is wrong, it accepts `abacb`, among other invalid strings. You also have a lot of superfluous epsilon transitions in your NFA, but that doesn't really matter. As a general rule, an equivalent DFA will almost always have more states than an NFA.

Comment: Also I'm assuming this is homework?

Comment: Yes, its homework. I am not asking for a solution, I just want to know if I am on the right track or not, and thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since this is very likely homework, I'm hesitant to just give you the complete correct solution.

Your NFA appears correct, but has a lot of superfluous states that aren't necessary but do not adversely affect its correctness. (At first glance it looks like you could remove 11 states.)

Your DFA is incorrect, though. This is because when you branch off to begin handling one condition of the string or the other, you later rejoin them together. This allows it to take the path from an accepted string matching `a(b|c)*a` and take in another `b` or `c` by travelling to nodes `15,17` or `11`. It then accepts this string even though it doesn't match your expression.

What you need to do is basically stop this from happening. If you have additional questions feel free to ask.

I highly recommend making a list of test strings that you know should be and shouldn't be accepted, and then trace them through, making sure your automata ends in the correct (accept or reject) state.

Comment: I just edited it, can you tell me if this is right? http://img263.imageshack.us/img263/7606/dfah.png Thanks!

Comment: +1, but the superfluous epsilon transitions aren't unrealistic: many automata toolkits produce a great deal of them.

Comment: `aa` isn't accepted now, but I think that's it (also the `c` in the loop at `15,17` disappeared). And yea I know they're not unrealistic, I've just always built automatas by hand so something like that is just unwieldy looking to me.

Comment: (Since this seems to have answered your question, you should accept it by clicking the check to the left of it, thanks `:)`)

Comment: Thanks Andrew! I don't like having so many epsilon in NFA either, but my professor said that I have to follow Thomson's algorithm and it requires you have have alot of epsilons. That's why I am using them excessively. Thanks once again.